# Use Authorize.net in Cognito Form to Pay Invoice

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I link my Authorize.net merchant account to a Cognito Form instead of using PayPal or Stripe?

I want to add a "Pay invoice" to a Cognito Form on our website. We also currently use Authorize.net for card not present payments.

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). Currently Cognito Forms does not support Authorize.Net for processing payments.

When payment support was first added to Cognito Forms, Authorize.Net did not offer a solution that fit with the road map of Cognito Forms. We have continued to look for ways to integrate with Authorize.Net and are currently working on getting this implemented.

Unfortunately, there is no current time-frame for release of Authorize.Net support, but you can follow progress on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/HXZe8y3Z).